# Qt Creator - Searching files with Locator including folder

Tags: qt-creator

One quick question about QtCreator : I know it is possible to use the locator to quickly open files by using the "Ctrl-K" shortcut.

However, is it possible to search for files including their locations?

For example, let's say I want to quickly locate a file named "main.cpp" in a folder named "myfolder" and I have lots of other main.cpp files.

What should I type into the locator in order to quickly open it ?

Comment: just learned the "Ctrl+K" shorcut. And I like it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just type myfolder/main.cpp in the locator